# Manually define size of frame using ggplot2 and geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, resize, facet-wrap

How can I manually define the size of the frames of individual graphs when plotting multiple boxplots using ggplot2?

If you e.g. have a 2x2 plot and each of the frames should be quadratic with 400x400 pixel height and width, you cannot set the dimension of the entire plot to 800x800 since there are still the axis texts (and these may be different in length due to the "scales="free_y" command in facet_wrap(~variable,scales="free_y")). This leads to "squeezed" instead of quadratic frame sizes.

```
p<-ggplot(data=data.frame,aes(x=x,y=value))+
geom_boxplot(size=0.1, fill="grey90")+
geom_point(aes(x=x, y=value, fill="black"),inherit.aes=FALSE, colour="red", size=2, position=position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.25), show.legend=FALSE)+
facet_wrap(~variable,scales="free_y")+
theme_bw()
```

Expected result: graph frames should always be quadratic with height and width defined by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with gtables in the following way. First we'll build a plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
# I don't have your data so I'll just use the diamonds dataset
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = price)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ clarity, scales = "free_y")
```

Then we'll convert the plot to a gtable, get the panel positions and adjust the widths and heights to our liking.

```
gt <- ggplotGrob(p)
# Usually panels don't span multiple cells in the table, so we can take the
# left ("l") and top ("t") positions of the panels.
panel_x <- panel_cols(gt)[,"l"]
panel_y <- panel_rows(gt)[,"t"]
gt$widths[panel_x]  <- unit(400/72, "inches")
gt$heights[panel_y] <- unit(400/72, "inches")

grid.newpage(); grid.draw(gt)
```

Unfortunately the `unit()` function doesn't let you specify dimensions in pixels, so I've assumed that the resolution of your output would be 72 pixels per inch. Have a look at `?unit` to see the options.

EDIT:

This is what the above looks like (with `unit(100/72, "inches")` for brevity):

[image]

Now if you also want the strips (the text that look like panel titles in a darker box) to be included in the 400x400 box, you might want to find the strip positions along the rows and subtract these from the units you supply.

```
gt <- ggplotGrob(p)
panel_x <- panel_cols(gt)[,"l"]
panel_y <- panel_rows(gt)[,"t"]
strip_y <- unique(gt$layout$t[grepl("strip", gt$layout$name)])
gt$widths[panel_x]  <- unit(100/72, "inches")
gt$heights[panel_y] <- unit(100/72, "inches") - gt$heights[strip_y]

grid.newpage(); grid.draw(gt)
```

Which looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! Definitely an interesting approach but it seems to sets the dimensions of the panel but not of the individual frame. When using your code, the individual boxplot frames are still different in height and width. I added a quick graphical example for clarification what dimensions I need to set to a defined value -> [link](https://ibb.co/zQXhHSP). The length of the red arrows in the picture should be set to defined values so they are always quadratic.

Comment: The example you provide looks like the result of a `facet_grid()` instead of a `facet_wrap()`.  Also, I'm not quite sure what exactly you mean when you say 'frame'; to my mind, what you've indicated with the red arrows is the panel, so would you mind expanding on what you mean by frame? Do you mean including the strips? Do you mean excluding the default 10% margin around the objects?

Comment: Since I am lacking the appropriate word (sorry, not too familiar with r terms), let me make it simpler and say that I mean the frame that is bordering the two boxplots it the picture provided (usually a box with black edges). The picture is probably facet_grid but was just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Right, I'll update my answer with some options and illustrations!

Comment: Thanks very much - this is exactly what I was looking for! Much appreciated!